# How to see all kernel menu options in Yocto?

Tags: yocto

I want to enable the kernel options using menu config in Yocto - Sumo.
I am using the following command

bitbake linux-yocto -c menuconfig

```
Symbol: ZONE_DMA [=n]                                                                                                                                                                                                                 Type  : boolean                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Defined at arch/powerpc/Kconfig:695
```

Where shall I go in menuconfig to enable this option?
I have tried searching everywhere but I couldn't find.

Comment: Not all enabling and disabling options are listed in the menuconfig.